# Searching 2D array and returning Point2D object in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a 15-piece sliding tile game, where the user tries to arrange tiles 1-15 in order on a grid. I'm stuck on an early part where, after the user enters a tile label, we locate where the tile currently is on the board. My aim is to search the 2D array where the tiles are located for the given tile, and then, once located, set a Point2D object's x and y values to the row and column of the found tile. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong with this. Any help?

```
package tilegame;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TileGame 
{
    public TileGame()
    {
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard(); 
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userTileNumber = 0;

        while (userTileNumber != -1)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter tile number: ");
            userTileNumber = user_input.nextInt(); 

            if (userTileNumber < 0) //terminates game if user enters -1
                break;
            else
                continue;
        }

        getTilePosition(userTileNumber);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new TileGame();
    }
}

class GameBoard
{
    int [][] tiles = { {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    //-1's represent the boundaries of the gameboard
                       {-1,  1,  2,  3,  4, -1},
                       {-1, 5, 6, 7, 8, -1},
                       {-1, 9, 10, 11, 12, -1},
                       {-1, 13, 14, 0, 15, -1},     //zero represents an empty space
                       {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1} };

    public GameBoard()
    {
        printGameBoard(tiles);
    }

    private void printGameBoard(int[][] tiles)  //Prints current position of all the tiles on the board
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < tiles[0].length; j++)
           {
              System.out.printf("%5s ", tiles[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public Point2D getTilePosition(int userTileNumber)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < tiles[i].length; j++)
           {
               if (tiles[i][j] == userTileNumber)
               {
                   Point2D searchedTile = new Point2D(i,j);
                   return searchedTile;
               }
           }
        }

        System.out.print("Tile number: " + userTileNumber + "/nRow: " + i + "/nColumn: " + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. This part of code had to be upgraded

```
 while (userTileNumber != -1)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter tile number: ");
        userTileNumber = user_input.nextInt(); 

        if (userTileNumber < 0) //terminates game if user enters -1
            break;
        else
            continue;
    }

    getTilePosition(userTileNumber);
```

and the method getTilePosition had to return the value:

```
 public Point2D getTilePosition(int userTileNumber)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < tiles[i].length; j++)
           {
               if (tiles[i][j] == userTileNumber)
               {
                   Point2D searchedTile = new Point2D(i,j);
                   return searchedTile;
               }
           }
        }

        System.out.print("Tile number: " + userTileNumber + "/nRow: " + i + "/nColumn: " + j);
    }
```

Having this all together this is the code

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TileGame 
{
    public static final int BOUNDARY = -1;
    public static final int EMPTY    =  0;
    public static final int QUIT     = -1;
    public static final int MIN_TILE =  1;
    public static final int MAX_TILE = 15;

    public static class GameBoard
    {
        int [][] tiles = {
            {BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY},
            {BOUNDARY, 1 ,  2,     3,  4, BOUNDARY},
            {BOUNDARY, 5 ,  6,     7,  8, BOUNDARY},
            {BOUNDARY, 9 , 10,    11, 12, BOUNDARY},
            {BOUNDARY, 13, 14, EMPTY, 15, BOUNDARY},
            {BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY, BOUNDARY} };

        public GameBoard()
        {
            printGameBoard(tiles);
        }

        public int[][] getTiles()
        {
            return tiles;
        }

        public void setTiles(int[][] tiles)
        {
            this.tiles = tiles;
        }

        public int getTile(int x, int y)
        {
            return getTiles()[x][y];
        }

        public int[] getRow(int i)
        {
            return getTiles()[i];
        }

        public static boolean isValidTile(int tile)
        {
            return MIN_TILE <= tile && tile <= MAX_TILE; 
        }

        private void printGameBoard(int[][] tiles)  //Prints current position of all the tiles on the board
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
            {
               for(int j = 0; j < tiles[0].length; j++)
               {
                  System.out.printf("%5s ", tiles[i][j]);
               }
               System.out.println();
            }
        }

        public Point2D getTilePosition(int userTileNumber)
        {
            Point2D searchedTile = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < getTiles().length && null == searchedTile ; i++)
            {
               for(int j = 0; j < getRow(i).length && null == searchedTile; j++)
               {
                   if (getTile(i,j) == userTileNumber)
                   {
                       searchedTile = new Point2D.Double(i,j);
                   }
               }
            }
            return searchedTile;
        }
    } 

    public TileGame()
    {
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard(); 
        Scanner user_input  = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userTileNumber  = 0;

        while (QUIT != userTileNumber)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter tile number: ");
            userTileNumber = user_input.nextInt();
            if (QUIT != userTileNumber && GameBoard.isValidTile(userTileNumber))
            {
                Point2D searchedTile = gameBoard.getTilePosition(userTileNumber);
                int x = (int)searchedTile.getX();
                int y = (int)searchedTile.getY();
                System.out.format("Tile's position (x,y) is (%d,%d).%n", x,y);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new TileGame();
    }
}
```